# How to improve the display of images?

Tags: prestashop

After installing the template, there was a problem with displaying images on the listing. I will just add that everything was fine on the old template, I reloaded all the pictures, and as I upload them, they all have a dimension of 800x800 px. How can I fix this problem?
Here is the image:[image: WebView]

And here is the [link](https://medpak.com.pl/szukaj?controller=search&orderby=position&orderway=desc&search_query=Witamina%20D3&category_filter=0&submit_search=) to view problem.

Comment: Which is the problem? http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/8951/DYteQD.jpg

Comment: I have attached a screen on which you can see that the pictures do not line up next to each other. One picture is higher than the rest.

Comment: Try to regenerate pictures via admin panel Preferences -> Images -> Regenerate thumbnails

Comment: The problem is that some product names fill 2 lines and others only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS rules in your global.css:

```
@media(min-width:992px) {
    .products-block.grid.first-in-line {
        clear: left
    }
    .rtl .products-block.grid.first-in-line {
        clear: right
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. The problem is still visible. Look at the bottom of the category: https://medpak.com.pl/suplementy-diety/

Comment: Where did you do the modification I told you? I can't see it in the frontoffice.

Comment: So clear cache or remove CCC, because this rule is not applied in the frontoffice